# Font-face font quality issue( Firefox, Chrome, Opera)

Tags: css, font-face

Check the site:

http://tinyurl.com/caljnqb

I'm using font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SegoeUI';
    src: url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeui.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeui.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeui.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeui.svg#SegoeUI2') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    }
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SegoeUIBold';
    src: url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeuib.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeuib.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeuib.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeuib.svg#SegoeUI3') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SegoeUIItalic';
    src: url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeuii.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeuii.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeuii.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('{site_url}themes/site_themes/agile_records/fonts/segoeuii.svg#SegoeUI4') format('svg');
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    }
```

And there is the problem with output in Firefox, Chrome and Opera browsers. Everything looks OK on IE. Font looks sharp. Why does it happens? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Strange.. doesn't look like that for me. Interesting to see others' feedback. IE and FF look very much like screen 1, with slight fuzziness in FF but nothing like that second screen...

Comment: This is a very common problem, and has been answered here many times.  Please use search in the future first.

Comment: The font at the bottom looks like a different font altogether. Are you sure Firefox is loading SegoeUI at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

different browsers render fonts differently.

The solution I've used in the past is to re-arrange the order in which the fonts are supplied to the font face, based on which browser is rendering the page.  Usually my problems are in the earlier versions of IE so I've used a separate style sheet that offered the .woff file before the ttf file.  Because some browsers can only read certain font type files but can read both and stop looking after finding one that works.  If you re-arrange them you may be able to  use one that renders a bit better.

If you end up using separate css you can use the $_SERVER arrays http_user_agent property to set a font css based on the browser.

googles Droid font is a font that renders funny sometimes depending on the browser as well so researching that might help you find other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are a few tricks in ordering properly each format

See for example

> This is the Fontspring bulletproof syntax modified to serve the svg
>   first:

```
@font-face {
font-family: ‘MyWebFont’;
src: url(‘webfont.eot’);
src: url(‘webfont.eot?#iefix’) format(‘embedded-opentype’),
    url(‘webfont.svg#svgFontName’) format(‘svg’),
    url(‘webfont.woff’) format(‘woff’),
    url(‘webfont.ttf’)  format(‘truetype’);
}
```

From http://www.fontspring.com/blog/smoother-web-font-rendering-chrome

You may also take care of using the proper **mime type** for WOFF font , as of http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b

```
application/font-woff
```

to ensure proper handling by the browser